# How to programmatically change the parameter of the GridView cell?

Tags: android, gridview

I have the main screen (activity_main.xml). It has a GridView and 2 buttons (red and green). As the design of the GridView cell, I use a separate xml file (content.xml). I can adjust the image size, text color and other parameters of the cell in GridView by changing the parameters in the file (content.xml). How do I change the color of text in the file (content.xml) programmatically? When you press the red and green buttons in the file (activity_main.xml)?
[I drew a diagram](http://pixs.ru/showimage/123png_9347073_20615510.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object in your code that references the TextView object in your XML file.

```
View cell = findViewById(R.layout.content);
TextView cellText = cell.findViewById( // reference to the TextView in xml file );
cellText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

You might need to change some values here depending on your XML files.

Comment: Thank you for Your reply. But I am getting underline in red. Please look at the screenshot: http://pixs.ru/showimage/1234PNG_8141178_20616147.png

Comment: As you are using the file content.xml for your cell, the first line should be `View cell = findViewById(R.layout.content);` instead of `R.layout.drawer_item`

Comment: sorry for the confusion. The figure in the example, I used other names to make it easier to understand the problem. I have my actual project name:
1) main screen  - (activity_main.xml)
2) contents of the cell -  (drawer_item.xml)
3) text in drawer_item.xml  - (android:id="@+id/icon_text")

Comment: Try to  clean and rebuild the project to make sure the R.java file is correct. If the error still persists, add an id to the parent view in drawer_item.xml, such as `android:id="@+id/example"`. Then refer to the main View of the cell with `findViewById(R.id.example);`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. I posted your project. You can see the error
1) Project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxhi0uFKK3upSHZhd0JldVIzSHc/view?usp=sharing
2) Error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxhi0uFKK3upZF9CMTZCR0tpbTQ/view?usp=sharing